# No DeviceSupport for 9.1 in developer directory

Tags: ios, xcode, diskimage, ios9.1

Xcode is unable to install my app on an iPhone 6s with new 9.1 iOS version. It reports the device to be ineligible and when I select devices it says it cannot find the Developer Disk Image.
In fact once I went to:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

I just found directories up to 9.0. I tried copying that by giving name 9.1, but it did not work. Where do I find the developer disks for 9.1?

Comment: Are you running Xcode 7.1? I can build and run a 9.1 deployment app on my 9.1 iPhone 6S.

Comment: I have 7.0, where did you find Xcode 7.1? There was no available update. Of course if you are not mentioning the beta, as 9.1 is now the official release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally copied the directory from the bundle associated to the beta version, and for some reason it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed by downloading the latest version of xCode.

Comment: Yes, I did delete my Xcode and download a completely new version, that may be the key.

Comment: Indeed this worked for me as well. Small detail, I couldn't just drag Xcode to the Trash, I had to do `sudo rm -rf /Applications/Xcode.app` from command line.